# How does AppHarbor start a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, appharbor

I would like to expose a number of WCF web services in AppHarbor. However, it is unclear to me, how to actually start the services, once the code has landed at AppHarbor. My questions are very fundamental:

- Given a bunch of compiled code, how does AppHarbor know which dll/exe to execute? And which method on which class?
- Should I start the service hosts myself, or should I just provide an .svc file?

So, basically, I miss a clear picture of how AppHarpor figures out what code to execute, and in case of WCF web services, how these should be started.

Comment: as @Yanire Romero said you need to push your solution (all project code) to apphabor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find information:

https://appharbor.com/page/how-it-works

I have deployed multiple WCF services projects on appharbor. First you have to know that when you push your code to AppHarbor it will look for only one .sln file. If there are more it'll throw an error.

Once you have deployed yor sevice it will look something like this:

[image]

Now, AppHarbor will make a list of every available commit you have pushed into the server so it will let you choose whiche one of them will be the one activated.

Since Appharbor compiles and builds the entire solution, you would have to push the entire project folder and not only the .svc file.

How would it know how to start it? That depends on the .sln file since it compiles the project it would be the same as when you debug it on your local browser. You don't have to start anything, once you have choosen a build to deploy, appharbor will do all the hardwork.

I hardly recommend it for .NET solutions ;)

Hope it helps.

More links:

http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/deploying-your-first-application-using-git